# Does Latin have any words for specific numbers apart from the numbers themselves (akin to the English "dozen", for example)

Tags: word-request, numbers

In English, many numbers have specific words that denote them, distinct from the number itself. For example "dozen" means  group of 12; "gross" means 144; and "score" means 20. Similarly, I understand that French has the word "seizaine" meaning a group of 16, distinct from "seize", the word for the number 16 itself. (I don't actually know French, so I may be missing a subtlety here.)

Does Latin have any similar words for particular numbers?

Comment: I don't know if this applies but the words "primus" and "princeps" overlap somewhat in meaning. They can both mean "first."

Comment: There are unspecific numbers of course, *manipulus,* group, platoon; *manipulatim,* in heaps (handfuls). *Scala,* a series, e.g. of notes, steps.

Comment: As an aside, seeing as you mention seizaine in French, the English dozen comes from the French douzaine :)

Comment: In the etymology of "dozen" is also Latin: from Latin duodecim (“twelve”) (from duo (“two”) + decem (“ten”)) + -ana (“-ish”).

Comment: I don't know if I would describe *seizaine* as completely separate from *seize*; *-aine* can be added to many numerals, so it's rather analogous to English *-some* (as in "threesome", "foursome", "fivesome", etc.).

Comment: "Dozen" is not DIRECTLY from Latin, but from Italian dozzina, which in turn is from French douzaine. "dozen" is basically a commercial term ("set of twelve goods") which proliferated at the time when Venice and Genoa controlled much of international trade.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can think of at least these two:

- **decuria:** A group of ten things or people
- **centuria:** A group of a hundred people (not things), especially a military unit of 100, later 60 men

Answer (score 5):

Latin borrowed a number of words from Greek, including some with numeric meanings, such as *[monas](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/monas)* and *[trias](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/trias).*

There is also *[trīnitās](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/trinitas),* built out of Latin components.